# ProcEnv parameter issue from DllExport.MSBuild assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, dllexport

I'm currently working on a C# programme developped years ago (ended around 2018) that i have to update. It was developped on VS 2015 but i switched to VS 2022.
DllExport is used to change dll files managment status which seems to work with most of the files.
First i tried to use the same version of DllExport used at the time but after selecting the concerned projects and clicking on 'Apply' DllExport just seem to be blocked, no matter which and how many project I select. This appen with all the DllExport versions but the last one available so I've installed DllExport and UnmanagedExports nuGet latest versions (1.7.4 and 1.2.7)  on each project of my solution.

But for some reason after using this version i get twice the same couple of errors regarding a Dllexport.MSBuild Task:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.   EntryPoints

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ProcEnv" parameter is not supported by the "DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask" task loaded from assembly: RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild, Version=1.2.7.38851, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f52d83c1a22df51 from the path: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\cola\packages\UnmanagedExports.1.2.7\tools\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.dll. Verify that the parameter exists on the task, the  points to the correct assembly, and it is a settable public instance property. EntryPoints

I don't get why this appens, the lateste vesrion definitly contain the ProcEnv parameter.
Is there a specific setting i should use ?